# How to integrate circle CI with magento?

Tags: magento, integration-testing, circleci

I have tried to integrate circle CI with magento, and i have created Phpunit test for running this tests, in magento theses tests are working as expected, but in circle CI phpunit showing errors.
[image]

in circle.yml file i have given like this

```
machine:
  php:
    version: 5.4.5
dependencies:
   pre:
     - cd tests/unit
     - wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
     - chmod +x phpunit.phar
     - sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
   post:
     - cd tests/unit
     - phpunit
```

Magento Unit testing followed URL http://www.atwix.com/magento/php-unit-testing/

Comment: Looks like the answer below is correct, provide a path to your test files as and argument for phpunit

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to pass tests to run as arguments to phpunit like this descrbied in https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html ?

Comment: Oh, btw, I work in CircleCI and you can get more help if you come to our support.